# Как ускорить видео без потери качества?

Tags: ffmpeg

Как ускорить (замедлить) видео без потери качества?
исходник mp4 60 fps

```
E:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -ss 0 -t 403.85 -i "E:\d\input.mp4" -an -vf "setpts=0.0024760647078244*PTS" "E:\d\0.mp4"
```

ужимает заметно

Comment: Я не заметил ухудшения качества видео при замедлении в два раза (setpts=0.5*PTS). Выложите видео для примера.

Comment: А может вообще не конвертировать, только частоту кадров заменить?

Comment: И попробуй `-vcodec copy`

Comment: так а как частоту кадров заменить что бы скорость увеличилась без перекодировки? "-r" без "-vf" просто добавляет дубль кадры же

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/523465/724113

Answer (score 1):

Задайте необходимое качество видео опцией `-crf`.